# Referencing a table within a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two tables with id's "table1" and "table2". table2 is present inside the third column of table1. Now I want to reference the values in table2 using jquery. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: you can use `ids` to point to any object you like; simply `$('#table2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second table has id `table2` you can get it in jQuery via `$('#table2')`. To get **all** `<td>`'s in the table you can for instance use `$('#table2 td')`.

Comment: @Sanjay, could you accept the answer so other people can see the question has been answered?